# Writing bucket sort in C# using strings as values

Tags: c#, sorting, bucket-sort

I need help writing a program that takes in student info for three separate fields `(ID Number, first name, last name)`. Then, sorts the table alphabetically based on the `last name` field. The user will input the student data, then I would like it to separate the `last name` data into two buckets which will then be put into a bubble sort. I am having trouble with adding the data into separate buckets.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _123_Assignment2
{
    using System;
    using static System.Console;
    class Program
    {
        struct student
        {
            public int studentId;
            public string firstName;
            public string lastName;
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            student[] studentInfo = new student[20];
            string[] bucketLow = new string[0];
            string[] bucketHigh = new string [0];
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;

            WriteLine("Enter student ID number:");
            studentInfo[x].studentId = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

            while (studentInfo[x].studentId != 999)                
            {
                WriteLine("Enter first name:");
                studentInfo[x].firstName = ReadLine();
                WriteLine("Enter last name:");
                studentInfo[x].lastName = ReadLine();
                x++;
                WriteLine("Enter student ID number:");
                studentInfo[x].studentId = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < studentInfo.Length; j++)
            {    
                if (studentInfo[j].lastName.CompareTo(studentInfo[j + 1].lastName) > 0)
                    bucketLow[y] = studentInfo[j].lastName;
                else
                    bucketHigh[y] = studentInfo[j].lastName;
                y++;
            }                                                 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you're not doing homework, consider **Linq**

Comment: `"I am having trouble"` - What trouble?  Specifically what's the problem?

Comment: If you're not doing homework, and you are actually writing your own bubble sort, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I think it is homework  (`namespace _123_Assignment2`)

Comment: It is homework, the bubble sort comes later I understand how to do that. I was looking for help breaking the array up for bucket sort, I will use bubble sort to sort the buckets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, you can check my comments for explanation:

```
        student[] studentInfo = new student[20];

        //Make sure you initialize the correct number of variables on your string
        string[] bucketLow = new string[20];
        string[] bucketHigh = new string[20];
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        //I commented out this line since you are already asking for inputs on without going on your counter scenario

        //Console.WriteLine("Enter student ID number:");
        //studentInfo[x].studentId = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        //I made changes on this line, since, you are doing a condition based on the number of increment on your counter
        while (x <= 2)
        {
            //I put the enter student ID above since it will not be counted if it was put after the counter x
            Console.WriteLine("Enter student ID number:");
            studentInfo[x].studentId = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter first name:");
            studentInfo[x].firstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter last name:");
            studentInfo[x].lastName = Console.ReadLine();
            x++;

        }

        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {
            //Make sure you put group all your conditions on round brackets to achieve your desired condition
            if ((studentInfo[j].lastName.CompareTo(studentInfo[j + 1].lastName)) > 0)
                bucketLow[y] = studentInfo[j].lastName;
            else
                bucketHigh[y] = studentInfo[j].lastName;
            y++;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track I was looking for.

Comment: You can now accept it as an answer if this answers your question :) @CoreyColgan